# Double integral $\int{e^{t^2}}$over a triangle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the following integral
$$\int\int_D e^{{t}^{2}} dt~du$$ where $D$ is the triangle lying between the lines $u=0$, $u=t$, $t=1$

Now I understand that $\int e^{t^2}dt$ can never be solved analytically, so I'm guessing this question is going to involve some sort of change of limits?

From the given triangle, I have worked out that (tell me if this is right lol):
$$D = \{(u,t) : 0\leq u\leq 1,~0\leq t \leq u \}$$
and that the triangle has coordinates $(1,0), (0,0) \text{ and } (1,1)$

So I would imagine that now the integral becomes:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^u e^{t^2} dt~du~~?$$

But I still can't figure out how to do the integral. So am I getting somewhere?If I'm then how am suppose to carry on?

Comment: I think you've got the wrong triangle.  You most likely want $$D=\{(u,t):0\le u\le t, 0\le t\le 1\}$$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

$\int\limits_{t=0}^1 \int\limits_{u=0}^t e^{t^2}\ dt\ du = {e - 1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did the integral $\int_0^t e^{t^2} dt$

Answer (score 0):

In the D, you can do the integration with respect to $t$ first or $u$ first, and the result is identical. For the first case, select an arbitrary fixed $u$ and draw a horizontal line across the D and find the intersects, namely $u$ and $1$, and the two values of t are the limits of inner integral. And where is u? Just sweeping the $u$ through the entire region of D, you can find $u$ goes from $0$ to 1, which is the limits for outer integral. For the second case, just refers to the case one.
$$\int_0^1(\int_u^1e^{t^2}dt)du=\int_0^1(\int_0^te^{t^2}du)dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} Erfi(1)=1.46$$
$Erfi(x)=\int_0^te^{t^2}dt$ is the imaginary error function.